# EXCEL VBA Find All Blank Cells in Columns C:O and then color them red

Tags: vba, excel

If a cell is empty, I need to fill it with a red color (colorindex=3)
The range is C6:O735.

I tried this code but it did not work.

```
Sub Empty_Cells()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("C6:O735")

    'color only blank cells
    myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

Additionaly, say for example cell K89 is empty, then I want to fill that empty cell with a red color AND the A89 of that same row too.

The purpose is when you go to A column and filter cells with red color, you can see all columns that have an empty cell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Conditional Formatting can help you too with this regard.

Answer (score 1):

But if you want to do it in VBA then you can try this:

```
Sub Lege_Cellen()
    Dim myRange As Range,cel As Range
    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("C6:O735")

    For each cel in myRange 
      if Trim(cel.value) = "" then cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next cel
End Sub
```